# Save R object to .RData-file

Tags: r, shiny

I created an object in the R-package "phyloseq".

I want to save the object as .RData to use it in "shiny-phyloseq".

I used the following command `save(phyill, file="~/Documents/Data/phyill.RData")`

Unfortunately the file does not appear in my folder.

What am I missing?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: The problem solved itself. The command would not work while "shiny-phyloseq" was running.

Comment: That's because the console is busy when an app is running, so you cannot do anything else in R until after you close the application.